# extracting numbers from list of strings with python

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I have a list of strings that I am trying to parse for data that is meaningful to me. I need an ID number that is contained within the string. Sometimes it might be two or even three of them. Example string might be:

```
lst1 = [
    "(Tower 3rd floor window corner_ : option 3_floor cut out_large : GA - floors : : model lines : id 3999595(tower 4rd floor window corner : option 3_floor: : whatever else is in iit " new floor : id 3999999)", 
    "(Tower 3rd floor window corner_ : option 3_floor cut out_large : GA - floors : : model lines : id 3998895(tower 4rd floor window corner : option 3_floor: : id 5555456 whatever else is in iit " new floor : id 3998899)"
]
```

I would like to be able to iterate over that list of strings and extract only those highlighted id values.

Output would be a `lst1 = ["3999595; 3999999", "3998895; 5555456; 3998899"]` where each id values from the same input string is separated by a colon but list order still matches the input list.

Comment: Please format your question properly. It can be really off-putting for an answerer.

Comment: I've also updated my answer, going in the same way as @alecxe. The point here is always to find a pattern in which you can extract the id.

Comment: +1 This question is perfectly legitimate and on-topic, if very basic (OP doesn't know about regexes). For the general hostile attitude to newbies, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254881/the-many-shades-of-newbie-ness et al.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `id\s(\d{7})` regular expression.

Iterate over items in a list and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the results of [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) call by `;`:

```
import re

lst1 = [
    '(Tower 3rd floor window corner_ : option 3_floor cut out_large : GA - floors : : model lines : id 3999595(tower 4rd floor window corner : option 3_floor: : whatever else is in iit " new floor : id 3999999)',
    '(Tower 3rd floor window corner_ : option 3_floor cut out_large : GA - floors : : model lines : id 3998895(tower 4rd floor window corner : option 3_floor: : id 5555456 whatever else is in iit " new floor : id 3998899)'
]

pattern = re.compile(r'id\s(\d{7})')
print ["; ".join(pattern.findall(item)) for item in lst1]
```

prints:

```
['3999595; 3999999', '3998895; 5555456; 3998899']
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @alecxe solution you can also do it without any imports.

If your id numbers are always after `id` and have a fixed (7) number of digits I would probably just use `.split('id ')` to separate it and get the 7 digits from the second block onwards.

You can put them together in the desired format by using `'; '.join()`

Putting everything together:

```
pattern = ['; '.join([value[:7] for value in valueList.split('id ')[1:]]) for valueList in lst1]
```

Which prints out:

```
['3999595; 3999999', '3998895; 5555456; 3998899']
```

Comment: they are not actually between ** i was trying to make them bold in the browser so that they stand out. i just edited the string to proper format. My bad.